# Trouble passing req to authenticate function in app.js

Tags: node.js, express

In the app.js file of an express app I'm getting undefined on req.params.company.  Here's the relevant code...

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var authenticate = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass, req, res, next, callback) {
    Auth = mongoose.model('Auth');
    Auth.findOne({ token: user }, function(err, authObject){
            if (err) return next(err);
        //The next line is where the problem lies.  Req.params.company is undefined.    
            var result = (user === authObject.token && req.params.company === authObject.companyName);
            console.log('result = ' +result);
            return result;
            //callback(null /* error */, result);
            })
});



app.get('/api/:company', authenticate, api.company);
```

I don't think it's relevant to the question, but just in case here is the code from my auth.js model.

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

function toLower (v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
}

var authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    token : { type : String, required : true, unique : true, index: true, set: toLower },
    companyName : { type : String, set: toLower },
    brandName : { type : String, set: toLower },
    active : Boolean
});

var Auth = mongoose.model('Auth', authSchema);
```

And finally for context, the objective of this code is simply to authenticate a token that is being passed as the user variable in http basic auth (password is null).  I also attempt to authorize the token for the company name that is given as a route parameter.

Can someone help me to understand why req.params.company would be coming back as undefined? If I log "req" by itself I get back "[Function]".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for code in the wrong place. Maybe do a console.log(arguments). Also, here's a link to code that could help: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-basic-authentication

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "looking for code in the wrong place".  I did log the arguments already.  As mentioned in the question doing that prints [Function] in the console for the req argument.  The link you shared is a helpful article.  I'm familiar with it and referred to it heavily when writing the code shared above in question.  Perhaps your answer would be better placed as a comment.